Delete first image deletes the product
i have this issue in laravel 9.19 php 8.1 when i delete any image from the product it works, except deleting the first image that deletes the whole product.
//products/edit.blade
<div class="d-flex flex-wrap">
    @foreach($product->images as $image)
        <div class="m-2">
            @php echo route('products.images.destroy', [$product->id, $image->id])@endphp
            <img src="{{ asset('storage/' . $image->image_url) }}" class="img-thumbnail"
                 style="width: 150px; height: 150px;" alt="">
            <form action="{{ route('products.images.destroy', [$product->id, $image->id]) }}"
                  method="POST" style="display: inline-block;">
                @csrf
                @method('DELETE')
                <button type="submit"
                        class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">{{ __('messages.delete') }}</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    @endforeach
</div>

//ProductController.php
public function destroyImage($productId, $imageId)
{
    // Check if the image exists
    $image = ProductImage::where('product_id', $productId)
        ->where('id', $imageId)
        ->first();

    if (!$image) {
        return redirect()->route('products.edit', $productId)
            ->withErrors(__('messages.image_not_found'));
    }

    // Delete the image file from storage
    Storage::delete($image->image_url);

    // Delete the image record from the database
    $image->delete();

    return redirect()->route('products.edit', $productId)->with('success', __('messages.image_deleted_successfully'));
}


public function destroy($id)
{
    $product = Product::findOrFail($id);

    // Delete associated images
    foreach ($product->images as $image) {
        Storage::delete('public/products/' . $image->image_url);
        $image->delete();
    }

    // Delete translations
    $product->translations()->delete();

    // Delete the product
    $product->delete();

    return redirect()->route('products.index')
        ->with('success', __('messages.product_deleted'));
}

//web.php
Route::middleware(['custom.auth'])->group(function () {
    // Categories (CRUD)
    Route::resource('categories', CategoryController::class);

    // Route to delete a specific product image
    Route::delete('/images/{product}/{image}', [ProductController::class, 'destroyImage'])
        ->name('products.images.destroy');

    // Ensure this comes after the above route
    Route::resource('products', ProductController::class);


});

i tried to delete a specific image from the product, it works but deleting the first image points to the destroy method instead of the destroyImage method

Show us your migrations or table structure

Then I’m guessing you have a constrained foreign key, and deleting the image will delete related records (i.e. the product). Your routes could also be organised a bit better and made more “resourceful”.

images should be a polymorph, you can have images in users, products etc etc..
